# MySQL and JavaFX syntax issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use JavaFX combo boxes to display data on a MySQL database. When the user selects the country, it is supposed to then display the regions available within that country. I modeled my code after another program which works with no issues, but this one is throwing a syntax error. I can't figure out the problem. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```java
public static ObservableList<String> addCustAreas(String inputCountry) throws SQLException {
    ObservableList getAreas = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    PreparedStatement sqlCommand = helper.getConnection().prepareStatement(
        "SELECT c.Country, c.Country_ID, d.Division_ID, d.Division FROM countries as c " +
        "RIGHT OUTER JOIN first_level_divisions AS d ON c.Country_ID = d.Country_ID " +
        "WHERE c.country = ?");
    sqlCommand.setString(1, inputCountry);
    ResultSet results = sqlCommand.executeQuery();

    while (results.next()){
        getAreas.add(results.getString("Division"));
    }
    sqlCommand.close();
    return getAreas;
}
```

The error message I receive is...

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL Syntax. Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use at "?" near line 1

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: It says, Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL Syntax. Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use at "?" near line 1.

Comment: please keep the tags focused - a syntax error in sql statement is unrelated to fx: do as the error message tells you, only if that's fixed go on to use it in a ui

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see the problem with the syntax. I would check the manual, like the error message suggests, or at least some online tutorial or Stack Overflow question that shows the correct syntax.